# Using underscore.js, is there a way to determine when a template has finished rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, template-engine

I'm working on a project and we're using underscore.js for templating. Is there a way to determine when the template has finished rendering so that I can then cue another function call?

This project includes jQuery but does not include Backbone.js if that helps in your answers.

Thanks!
Mike

Comment: Well, `_.template` returns a function which does the actual evaluation of the template. That function returns the result as string. So whenever the function returns, the rendering is done, it is not asynchronous. Just put the function call after the rendering call. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I guess that is what I was trying to figure out, if it was asynchronous or not. That probably answers the question. Thanks Felix!

Comment: Ok :) Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_.template` returns a function which does the actual evaluation of the template. That function returns the result as string. So whenever the function returns, the rendering is done, it is not asynchronous.

Example from the documentation:

```
var compiled = _.template("hello: <%= name %>");
compiled({name : 'moe'});
=> "hello: moe"
```

So you can simple put the next function call after the rendering call:

```
var compiled = _.template("hello: <%= name %>");
var result = compiled({name : 'moe'});
someOtherFunction();
```